# Table of contents problems

Tags: bibliographies, table-of-contents, appendices

I am writing my thesis and I am having a few problems with my format. My thesis structure is as follows:

> I Introduction
>
> II Part 1
>
> - chapter 1
> - chapter 2
>
> III Part 2
>
> - chapter 3
> - chapter 4
>
> Appendices
>
> Bibliography

My problem is this:

In my table of contents, this appears like this:

> I Introduction
>
> II Part 1
>
> - chapter 1
> - chapter 2
>
> III Part 2
>
> - chapter 3
> - chapter 4
>
> IV Appendices
>
> - bibliography

So two questions:

1. How do I remove the part number for the Appendices
2. How do I bump up the bibliography to the `{part}` level in the table of contents (this entry is automatically generated by the `\bibliography` at the moment)

I really appreciate any help!!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that it is unusual around here to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to have any greeting. I took the liberty to reformat your post so that it can be easier read (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help for details about how post can be formatted).

Comment: AFAIK the bibliography is normally not mentioned in the ToC because its position is fixed at the very end. But I can understand that you want to include it.

Comment: A [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be very helpful. At the very least, we need to know a) your document class b) what packages (if any) you use for the bibliography.

Answer (score 3):

how you get the bibliography treated as a part in the t-of-c depends on how
it's defined in the documentclass you're using.  however, i assume that you
want the appearance of the bibliography itself to remain with the first page
looking like the first page of a chapter.

the two documentclasses with parts with which i'm most familiar (the latex book.cls
and amsbook.cls) both start `{thebibliography}` as `\chapter*` (though in slightly
different ways).  the main difference is that book.cls doesn't put anything into
the t-of-c for `\chapter*`.  with such a class, all you need to do is enter something like

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Bibliography}
```

after `\begin{thebibliography}` and before the first reference entry.

for a class like amsbook.cls, which automatically writes a t-of-c entry, you
would need to suppress that and then add a replacement.  the deletion can be
accomplished by defining a command such as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SkipTocEntry}[4]{}
```

(using [5] instead if you're loading hyperref).  then, just before the start
of the bibliography, insert

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\SkipTocEntry}
```

and proceed as above with the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

```
\part*
```

would remove the number for the Appendix most probably.

For the Bibliography, it really depends on your style I guess, but you could try:

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{\part*{Bibliography}}
```